# fix python failed script For loops

Tags: python

What changes should be made to this script to make it print the desired result?

```
def dummy(url):
      req = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8').replace("\n","")
      getTag = re.search('<div class="eps_lst_tbn">(.*?)<div class="clear"></div>', req).group(1)
      judul = re.findall('<div class="node">\r\t\t\t<div>(.*?)</div>',getTag)
      link = re.findall('<a href="(.*?)">',getTag)
      episode = re.findall('</a>\r\t\t\t<div>(.*?)</div>',getTag)
      l=[]
      num = 1
      for i in link:
        x = '<br/>(%s) %s - %s <a target="_blank">%s</a>' %(num,judul,episode,i)
        l.append(x)
        num = num+1
      string = ''.join(l[0:3])
      return string
```

Current results:

```
(1) ['a', 'b', 'c'] - ['1', '2', '3'] <u>http://url.com/a/1/</u>
(2) ['a', 'b', 'c'] - ['1', '2', '3'] <u>http://url.com/b/2/</u>
(3) ['a', 'b', 'c'] - ['1', '2', '3'] <u>http://url.com/c/3/</u>
```

Desired results:

```
(1) a - 1 <u>http://url.com/a/1/</u>
(2) b - 2 <u>http://url.com/b/2/</u>
(3) c - 3 <u>http://url.com/c/3/</u>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`judul` and `episode` are not strings, they are lists of strings. If you want to show a single string for each of them, you must use indexing.

```
for idx, href in enumerate(link):
    x = '<br/>(%s) %s - %s <a target="_blank">%s</a>' %(idx+1,judul[idx],episode[idx],href)
    l.append(x)
```